# stuck on android emulator Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin

I have an xamarin application and I believe I at some point tried to run android but now I just have "android emulator" at the run bar and I cant find a way to switch this back to "localhost" to just run on my pc normally? is there any way to fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xamarin is enviroment to develop mobile application, and to do so you need to use either Android Emulator (or if you are making IOS app, you need IOS Emulator), or physical device. You can try to delete emulator, to do so you need to go to `Tools>Android>Android Device Manager` and then uinstall it, but you won't be able to run your app

[image]

Comment: I fixed it, I just had to reload the application and click the white panel next to the play button to select Android, iOS or UWP